# How does shuffling work with ImageDataGenerator in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm creating an image classification model with Inception V3 and have two classes. I've split my dataset and labels into two numpy arrays.The data is split with trainX and testY as the images and trainY and testY as the corresponding labels.

```
data = np.array(data, dtype="float")/255.0
labels = np.array(labels,dtype ="uint8")

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(
                                data,labels, 
                                test_size=0.2, 
                                random_state=42) 

train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
          zoom_range = 0.1,
          width_shift_range = 0.2, 
          height_shift_range = 0.2,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          fill_mode ='nearest') 

val_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        trainX, 
        trainY,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow(
                testX,
                testY,
                batch_size=batch_size)
```

When I shuffle train_generator with ImageDataGenerator, will the images still match the corresponding labels? Also should the validation dataset be shuffled as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the images will still match the corresponding labels so you can safely set `shuffle` to `True`. Under the hood it works as follows. Calling `.flow()` on the `ImageDataGenerator` will return you a `NumpyArrayIterator` object, which implements the following logic for shuffling the indices:

```
def _set_index_array(self):
    self.index_array = np.arange(self.n)
    if self.shuffle: # if shuffle==True, shuffle the indices
        self.index_array = np.random.permutation(self.n)
```

`self.index_array` is then used to yield both the images (`x`) and the labels (`y`) (code truncated for readability):

```
def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):
    batch_x = np.zeros(tuple([len(index_array)] + list(self.x.shape)[1:]),
                       dtype=self.dtype)
    # use index_array to get the x's
    for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
        x = self.x[j]
        ... # data augmentation is done here
        batch_x[i] = x
     ...
     # use the same index_array to fetch the labels
     output += (self.y[index_array],)

    return output
```

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image.py) yourself, it might be easier to understand than you think.

Shuffling the validation data shouldn't matter too much. The main point of shuffling is to introduce some extra stochasticity in the training process.

Answer (score 1):

shuffle is "True" per default, so you must add

```
 train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        trainX, 
        trainY,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False)
```